# Angular Update from v5.2 to v6.1 not to v7.x

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5

I'm following the steps to upgrade Angular to v6.1 from v5.2 using Angular update site - https://update.angular.io/, but we don't want to jump to v7.x due to the amount of changes in the update and jumping multiple major versions is not suggested.

What would I change in the update steps provided by Angular so I don't update directly to v7 until v6.1 has been pushed out and tested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install corresponding version of Angular CLI to produce app with needed Angular version.
In your case try to install it like this

```
npm i @angular/cli@v6-lts -g
```

Check out versions list in [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli)

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing!  Thanks found the versions at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli?activeTab=versions

Comment: Specifically when following Angular's update guide the command changes for a specific version of Angular would be `yarn global add @angular/cli@v6-lts`, `yarn add @angular/cli@v6-lts`,  `ng update @angular/cli`, `ng update @angular/core@6.1.10`, and then follow the rest of the guide

Answer (score 0):

Along with the steps given in the provided link, for upgrading angular to specific version in your package.json upgrade to specific angular packages eg

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "6.1.0",
  }
```

If you further want to specify the major/minor versions you can use '^' & '~' in front of the version.
eg

```
^6.1.0
```

- Note: If you upgrade @angular/cli with the steps to new apps you will create will be bootstrapped using new Angular version. if you want to avoid that then you need to uninstall cli version and clear cache.